# Python Eventlet + Javascript Websocket returns Blob

Tags: javascript, python, json, websocket, eventlet

I am experimenting with Python's Eventlet Websocket support, using [this simple example](http://eventlet.net/doc/examples.html#websocket-server-example) :

```
import eventlet
from eventlet import wsgi
from eventlet import websocket
from eventlet.support import six

# demo app
import os
import json
import time
import random


@websocket.WebSocketWSGI
def handle(ws):
    """  This is the websocket handler function.  Note that we
    can dispatch based on path in here, too."""
    if ws.path == '/echo':
        while True:
            ws.send("hello")
            #ws.send(json.dumps({"msg":"hello"}))
            time.sleep(1)

    elif ws.path == '/data':
        for i in six.moves.range(10000):
            ws.send("0 %s %s\n" % (i, random.random()))
            eventlet.sleep(0.1)


def dispatch(environ, start_response):
    """ This resolves to the web page or the websocket depending on
    the path."""
    if environ['PATH_INFO'] == '/data':
        return handle(environ, start_response)
    else:
        start_response('200 OK', [('content-type', 'text/html')])
        return [open(os.path.join(
                     os.path.dirname(__file__),
                     'websocket.html')).read()]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # run an example app from the command line
    listener = eventlet.listen(('127.0.0.1', 7000))
    print("\nVisit http://localhost:7000/ in your websocket-capable browser.\n")
    wsgi.server(listener, dispatch)
```

I'm not going to include the entire websocket handler I have in the Javascript, just the `ws.onmessage` method:

```
ws.onmessage = function (evt)
{
   console.log(evt.data)
   var received_msg = evt.data;
   #Do stuff, i.e var obj = JSON.parse(received_msg)
   #callback(obj)
};
```

The `console.log(evt.data)` indicates a succesful connection with the websocket (and you can assume this is all fine). However, the logging shows `Blob {size: 31, type: ""}` as the content of `evt.data`. I assume this is some kind of response object which is interpreted as binary (file) data (though I might be entirely wrong), but I'm not sure what to do with this.

I see that Blob data is often the data type for file-like objects. I suppose I could approach it as such, but I really only want to send json data back and forth. I've tried dumping a dict as a JSON and sending that, but it did the same. Even a string is received in Blob format.

How do I use `eventlet` for json data transmission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 2017-05 Eventlet websocket API does not support string websocket frames. Patches are welcome, it's easy.

Your options:

- read Blob at javascript end [FileReader.readAsText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader)
- use another websocket library (pure Python implementation will work fine with Eventlet patching)
- add string frame support to Eventlet websocket library

Comment: The first option is quite straightforward and I tested it successfully. Do you know if creating a FileReader is a costly/slow procedure? Thanks!

Comment: 1) think how would you implement it, allocating a buffer sounds plausible
2) of course, it consumes some measurable amount of resources - browsers provide extensive debugging tools these days
3) whether this amount is relevant for your application - this can not be judged by a random person from internet who has not seen your application
4) combining above, do you really seek for a comforting line rather than technical performance question? Lennart, everything will be fine, please continue with your project.
http://ubiquity.acm.org/article.cfm?id=1513451